# basename and find return in unix

Tags: bash, unix

i have this structure in my find return:

```
.//r-repos/gbm/DESCRIPTION
.//r-repos/GCD/DESCRIPTION
.//ggplot2/DESCRIPTION
```

i want to show only parent folders of DESCRIPTION file (gbm, gcd,ggplot2) but i dont know why is "ggplot2" the only output on the screen.

```
r_path=$(find "$dossierpath"  -iname DESCRIPTION -exec dirname {} \;)
for var in "$r_path" 
do 
 basename "$var"
done
```

what i have:
output: ggplot2

what i want: output: gbm, gcd,ggplot2

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have decided to quote your variable: `$r_path`, which is the return of your `find` command.

If you have spaces and/or newline characters, etc in your directory names, I would recommend something like this instead:

```
find "$dosierpath" -iname DESCRIPTION -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do

    basename "$(dirname "$file")"
done
```

Comment: Just to be clear the quoting is an issue because the value of `$r_path` is being treated as a single "word" and so the loop only executes once and so `basename` only executes once.